# NDSolve showing problem with initial and B.C

Tags: differential-equations

I have to solve for $\psi_{1}$, $\psi_{0}$ and $\psi_{-1}$ the following GP Equations Using initial Condition as 
$\psi_{j}=\sqrt{r_{j} n(x)}Exp(i \theta_{j})$, where $\sum_{j=1,0,-1}{r_{j}=1}.$ The GP Equations are:
$i \frac{\partial \psi_{1}}{\partial t}=-\frac{\partial^2 \psi_{1}}{2\partial x^2}+ c_{0}(|\psi_{1}|^2+|\psi_{0}|^2+|\psi_{-1}|^2)\psi_{1} + c_{2}[(|\psi_{0}|^2+|\psi_{-1}|^2)\psi_{1} + (\psi_{-1}^2 + \psi_{0}^2)\psi^*_{1}]$

$i \frac{\partial \psi_{0}}{\partial t}=-\frac{\partial^2 \psi_{0}}{2\partial x^2}+ c_{0}(|\psi_{1}|^2+|\psi_{0}|^2+|\psi_{-1}|^2)\psi_{0} + c_{2}[(|\psi_{1}|^2+|\psi_{-1}|^2)\psi_{0} + (\psi_{1}^2 - \psi_{-1}^2)\psi^*_{0}]$

$i \frac{\partial \psi_{-1}}{\partial t}=-\frac{\partial^2 \psi_{-1}}{2\partial x^2}+ c_{0}(|\psi_{1}|^2+|\psi_{0}|^2+|\psi_{-1}|^2)\psi_{-1} + c_{2}[(|\psi_{0}|^2+|\psi_{1}|^2)\psi_{-1} + (\psi_{1}^2 + \psi_{0}^2)\psi^*_{-1}]$

Also $n(z)=\frac{\mu}{c_{0}}$.
i tried with the following code but it shows error with boundry and initial conditions. I am actually calculating PRA 64, 021601(R)...

Thanks in anticipation.

Ahmed Abdullah.

```
    ClearAll;
    c0 == 1; c2 == -1; (a + b + c) == 1; Subscript[\[Theta], 0] == 0; 
    Subscript[\[Theta], 1] == \[Pi]/2; Subscript[\[Theta], 2] == 0; \[Mu] 
    ==125;
NLSE = {I\[Epsilon] D[\[Psi][1][t, x], {t, 1}] == -(1/
   2) \[Epsilon]^2 D[\[Psi][1][t, x], {x, 2}] + 
 c0 (Abs[\[Psi][1][t, x]]^2 + Abs[\[Psi][0][t, x]]^2 + 
    Abs[\[Psi][2][t, x]]^2) \[Psi][1][t, x] + 
 c2 (Abs[\[Psi][0][t, x]]^2 \[Psi][1][t, x] + 
    Abs[\[Psi][2][t, x]]^2 \[Psi][1][t, x] + 
    Conjugate[\[Psi][1][t, 
       x]] (\[Psi][2][t, x]^2 + \[Psi][0][t, x]^2)), 
 I \[Epsilon] D[\[Psi][0][t, x], {t, 1}] == -(1/
   2) \[Epsilon]^2 D[\[Psi][0][t, x], {x, 2}] + 
 c0 (Abs[\[Psi][1][t, x]]^2 + Abs[\[Psi][0][t, x]]^2 + 
    Abs[\[Psi][2][t, x]]^2) \[Psi][0][t, x] + 
 c2 (Abs[\[Psi][1][t, x]]^2 \[Psi][0][t, x] + 
    Abs[\[Psi][2][t, x]]^2 \[Psi][0][t, x] + 
    Conjugate[\[Psi][0][t, 
       x]] (\[Psi][1][t, x]^2 - \[Psi][2][t, x]^2)), 
I \[Epsilon] D[\[Psi][2][t, x], {t, 1}] == -(1/
   2) \[Epsilon]^2 D[\[Psi][2][t, x], {x, 2}] + 
 c0 (Abs[\[Psi][1][t, x]]^2 + Abs[\[Psi][0][t, x]]^2 + 
    Abs[\[Psi][2][t, x]]^2) \[Psi][2][t, x] + 
 c2 (Abs[\[Psi][1][t, x]]^2 \[Psi][2][t, x] + 
    Abs[\[Psi][0][t, x]]^2 \[Psi][2][t, x] + 
    Conjugate[\[Psi][2][t, 
       x]] (\[Psi][1][t, x]^2 - \[Psi][0][t, x]^2))};
xM = 5; \[Epsilon] = 0.06; \[Psi]1 = 
Sqrt[a n(z)] Exp[I (Subscript[\[Theta], 1])]; \[Psi]0 = 
Sqrt[b n(z)] Exp[I (Subscript[\[Theta], 0])]; \[Psi]2 = 
Sqrt[c n(z)] Exp[I (Subscript[\[Theta], 2])];
sol = With[{pp = 81}, 
NDSolve[{NLSE, \[Psi][1][0, x] == \[Psi]1, \[Psi][0][0, 
  x] == \[Psi]0, \[Psi][2][0, x] == \[Psi]2, \[Psi][1][t, +xM] == 
 0, \[Psi][0][t, +xM] == 
 0, \[Psi][2][t, +xM] == \[Psi]2, \[Psi][1][t, -xM] == 
 0, \[Psi][0][t, -xM] == 0, \[Psi][2][t, -xM] == 0}, {\[Psi][
 1], \[Psi][0], \[Psi][2]}, {t, 0, 10}, {x, -xM, +xM}, 
AccuracyGoal -> 2.5, PrecisionGoal -> 2.5, MaxSteps -> Infinity, 
Method -> {"MethodOfLines", 
 "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", 
   "DifferenceOrder" -> "Pseudospectral", "MaxPoints" -> pp, 
   "MinPoints" -> pp}}]]
```

Comment: You have one I\\[Epsilon] that should be I*\\[Epsilon] or I \\[Epsilon]. You should change c0 == 1; c2 == -1; Subscript[\\[Theta], 0] == 0; Subscript[\\[Theta], 1] == \\[Pi]/2; Subscript[\\[Theta], 2] == 0; \\[Mu] ==125; to c0=1; c2= -1; Subscript[\\[Theta], 0]=0; Subscript[\\[Theta], 1]=\\[Pi]/2; Subscript[\\[Theta], 2]=0; \\[Mu]=125; And then you have to find a way to assign constant numeric values to a,b,c,n,z. After those changes we can see what needs to be done next.

Comment: @ Bill; Thanks dear for responding. But giving z any constant value shows the error and I am not able to get time evolution like in the paper.  for time evolution i use : x = 0; Plot[
       Evaluate[{Abs[\[Psi][1][t, x]], Abs[\[Psi][0][t, x]], 
      Abs[\[Psi][2][t, x]]} /. First[sol]], {t, 0, 3}, PlotPoints -> 10,
      MaxRecursion -> 5, PlotRange -> {0, 10}]

Comment: Ahmed, this looks like a problem of a superconductive phase transition with the three-component wave function as the order parameter, right in the transition point. Am I right, or it is something else? If this is the case, the first thing that you should do is to rescale your system to get rid of the parameter c2. May be you will be able to get rid of the both c0 and c2. After that you will be able to apply `NDSolve`.

Comment: Continuation: The second thing: your condition on the ri is not clear. It requires r1+r2+r3=1. This cannot fix the initial conditions for all three functions. So, you should somehow clarify this point.

Comment: @ Alexei.... Thanks for the comment. Actually, it is for the study of modulational Instability, with 3 component order parameter. r1+r2+r3=1 is normalization condition. c0 and c2 are the nonlinearities and can be negative or positive